# iOS 11 SceneKit hitTest:options: fails

Tags: scenekit, ios11

I'm facing a difficult situation using hitTest:options: in SceneKit on iOS 11.

In a maping application I have a terrain node. Using hitTest:options: I was able for long to spot a point on the terrain from a touch on the screen. It still work as expected with released binary on iOS 11, and also on Xcode 9 compiled binary for iOS 10 simulator.

But iOS 11 binary on iOS 11 SDK gives totaly eratic results. Return array from hitTest:options: may contain no result or too many. Moreover, most of the time none of the results is valid. Here below are images to illustrate the point. All image are from a scene with no hidden node.

**Edit**: I made a test today using hitTestWithSegmentFromPoint:toPoint:options: and got false results also.

First with working simulator.

[image: one hit ok] It shows a normal hit on the terrain. The hit point is illustrated with a red ball. It is half inset in the terrain as its center is right on the terrain.

[image: 3 hits ok]
[image: 3 hits ok yaw]
These two images show a case where the "ray" cross the terrain 3 times. We got 3 hits all placed correctly on the terrain.The second image change the angle of view to show the 3 points.

Now the failing iOS 11 situation:

[image: one hit ko] On this picture we got one hit but it is "nowhere" between the two mountains, not on the terrain.

The last two pictures show other attempts with 4 and 16 hits, all "in the blue" with no connection to the terrain.

Sometimes the hit are "away" past the terrain, sometimes they are between the camera and the terrain.

[image: 4 hits ko]
[image: 16 hits ko]

Comment: I'm also facing with issues since iOS 11. The first thing, what helped me a lot was finding that Apple has changed the default searchMode to 'closest'. Give a try with the following options, I hope it will help.


if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
        {
            hitTestOptions[SCNHitTestOption.searchMode] = SCNHitTestSearchMode.all.rawValue
        }

Comment: Thanks @PéterKovács, that was exactly my problem. Works like a charm again.

Comment: For me, the all option does not resolve the issue. Still seeing points "in the blue"

Comment: Have you used SCNConstraints?

Comment: The scene involved has only one SCNLookAtConstraint constraint from the camera to a target node.

Comment: Péter Kovács answer was spot-on. FYI I also had an related issue where backfaceculling was not working as I also had [.boundingBoxOnly: true] in the HitTestOptions. This was causing it to ignore the [.backfaceCulling: true] option I also had set.

Comment: My problem is different. I received a followup on my bug report to Apple. They corrected 2 issues, relative to precision and triangle strips. So, I'll wait for the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four years latter I went back to this problem and found a solution to my original problem.

After Apple released iOS 11.2, multiples hits were solved but we got a "no hits" conundrum.

The problem lies in a specific situation that was not fully explained in the original question. After a terrain is originally computed and displayed we always get a first hit. Then we **pan** the terrain to center the hit point and rebuild a new terrain sector. In the process, we save computing by reusing severals geometry elements, only changing the z coordinates of the terrain vertexes. The problem lies in reusing the triangle strip `SCNGeometryElement`. From now on, any terrain built by reusing this object is fine looking but fails the hitTest method.

It turns out that the `SCNGeometryElement` can't be reused and should be rebuilt.
The originally working code was :

```
t_strip = [geom_cour geometryElementAtIndex:0];
```

To workaround the HitTest: failure we have to do :

```
//get current triangle strip
SCNGeometryElement *t_strip_g = [geom_cour geometryElementAtIndex:0];
//create a new one using the current as a template
t_strip = [SCNGeometryElement geometryElementWithData:t_strip_g.data
                                        primitiveType:t_strip_g.primitiveType
                                       primitiveCount:t_strip_g.primitiveCount
                                        bytesPerIndex:t_strip_g.bytesPerIndex];
```

The current `SCNGeometryElement` is used as a template to recreate a new one with exactly the same values.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem on iOS 11. My solution:

```
var hitTestOptions = [SCNHitTestOption.sortResults : NSNumber(value: true),
                      SCNHitTestOption.boundingBoxOnly : NSNumber(value: true)]

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    hitTestOptions[SCNHitTestOption.searchMode] = SCNHitTestSearchMode.all.rawValue as NSNumber
}
```

Comment: My bug report get follow-up by Apple. The bug is partly resolved on 11.2 beta. Still has some difficulties to get a point at all time.