# Scenekit hitTestWithSegment only returns first hit (all of a sudden)

Tags: xcode, swift3, scenekit

basically hitTestWithSegment returns the first hit only.

i have multiple nodes moving in the Z axis in rows of 1 to 3. similar to a game like rock band. when a row of 2 or more passes the segment, it only returns the first node on the left.

```
hit = scene.rootNode.hitTestWithSegment(from: SCNVector3(-3, 0, 0) , to: SCNVector3(3, 0, 0), options: nil)

if hit.count > 0{
   print(hit.count)
}
```

output: 1

i've also tried setting the options to

```
[SCNHitTestOption.firstFoundOnly.rawValue: false]
```

and i get the same thing.

I don't know what went wrong. hitTestWithSegment was working as expected all along till I opened xcode today. i didn't make any changes, no software updates, it just works differently now. I stripped all code to just essentially hit testing and i can't get more than 1 hit at a time

edit: i found a workaround, but i don't understand why it works or why it broke in the first place.

i swapped my from: to: vectors (3, 0, 0), (-3, 0, 0) and it works again

reversing the segment should only change which node gets returned first not how many.

edit: This is not on iOS, it's on Mac

Comment: See the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352867/ios-11-scenekit-hittestoptions-fails In other words, you need to set the searchmode option to all since ios 11.0.

Comment: thanks, that works. should it be provided as an answer and not a comment?

Comment: I posted it as a comment as I was about to report it as a duplicate, but the other question wasn’t exactly the same even though the answer is. I’ll post it as a answer. Glad it worked out.

Comment: In my eyes the direction of the segment shouldn't play any role here, no matter if the options are set to only return the first hit or all hits. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple decided to surprise everyone in IOS 11 by changing the default behavior of the hittest functions. Since IOS 11 you need to specfically tell the hittest to search for all nodes and not just return the first hit result:

```
hitTestOptions[SCNHitTestOption.searchMode] = SCNHitTestSearchMode.all.rawValue as NSNumber
```

This will set it back to returning an array of hitresults if multiple nodes were hit.

Comment: Any idea why hitTestWithSegment() expects strings in the options dictionary? Everywhere else (e.g. in SCNSceneRenderer's hitTest()) it expects the appropriate struct values which makes much more sense...